# Getting error "operation is not valid due to current state of the object" during new ASP.NET project creation in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web, visual-studio-2022

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 and trying to create a new project of ASP .NET web application to write a C#  web application . Every time I try to create a new project the system throws an error in the last step "operation is not valid due to current state of the object" and the process aborts . I have tried multiple times to uninstall  and reinstall VS but the error stays . Any help will be highly appreciated .

Regards
Sid

I tried to create a project and expected a project to get created and the solution explorer page to open .

Comment: what is the .net version? can you show us more details of the error, like screen pic?

Comment: Please provide some more information, such as the screenshots of the project you created and the screenshots of the error report. Also I recommend you to check if the location where you created the project has restricted access. If restricted, allow access for all roles.